# Why can't yum find inconsolata-fonts package available for install?

Tags: linux, yum, rpm

On CentOS v6.3 when I type:

```
yum update
```

followed by:

```
yum search inconsolata-fonts
```

or:

```
yum search inconsolata
```

I get no results.

However a Google search indicates that a package called `inconsolata-fonts` [is available](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=inconsolata-fonts).

How can I make `yum` find this without manually downloading the rpm using a browser?

Comment: Are you on CentOS, RedHad, Fedora, SuSe?

Comment: I'm on CentOS v6.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the page you linked to, these packages are in the [DAG packages for Red Hat Linux](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/) repository. You can add these to your system through `rpm-forge`.

The basic steps are (taken from [here](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge)):

1. Download the rpmforge-release package. Choose one of the two links below, selecting to match your host's architecture. If you are unsure of which one to use you can check your architecture with the command `uname -i`

   - i686 http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686.rpm
   - x86_64 http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
2. Install DAG's GPG key

   ```
   rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
   ```
3. Install the downloaded package

   ```
   rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.*.rpm
   ```
4. Now install your font

   ```
   yum install inconsolata-fonts
   ```